# Install Dlib on Windows

Tags: dlib

I want to install Dlib 19.9 on Windwos 10 with CMake cmake-3.5.0-rc1-win32-x86.
I use default setting in the CMake and the Configuration is ok with warnings: no CUDA and BLAS supported, I ignored these warning and click "Generate" button, but encounter the following error:

CMake Error in dlib/CMakeLists.txt:
  $ requires its parameter to be a reachable target.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

YL

Comment: `cmake-3.5.0-rc1-win32-x86` I would upgrade to a newer CMake. The current version is 3.10.2. Also this is a release candidate (meaning likely to still have a bug or two).

Comment: I use Cmake3.10 and it is resolved. But when I load the Project.sln, I cannot see all header files. Only .cpp and .c are listed in the solution Explorer. How to load all .h files?  Many thanks!

Comment: You need to put the headers as dependencies for the target in your CMakeLists.txt in the same way as you do for .cpp files.

Comment: Thanks drescherjm!